# Sum 4 integer from a 128 bit __m128 Intel Intrinsic

Tags: c, caching, optimization, intel, intrinsics

I have a __m128 intrinsic element of 128 bits. It contains 32 bit integers. Is there an easy way to sum all four of these integers? I am concerned with speed and cache optimization, so I'm trying to avoid storing the 128 in an array and then grabbing the elements from the array.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's the fastest way, but you could convert to m128i, shift into another register, and use __m128i_mm_add_epi8. You'd even get 2 of the 3 additions in one go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pair of phaddd instructions might be the best solution. Here is an example:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__m128i add_32X4 (__m128i value)
    {
    __m128i result;

    result = _mm_hadd_epi32 (value, value);
    result = _mm_hadd_epi32 (result, result);
    return result;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void)
    {
    __m128i input = _mm_set_epi32 (1, 10, 100, 1000);
    __m128i result = add_32X4 (input);
    printf ("%d\n", _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (result));
    return 0;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

program output:
`1111`

sample code generation (gcc 4.8.1):

```
<add_32X4>:
 30:    66 0f 6f 01             movdqa xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rcx]
 34:    66 0f 38 02 c0          phaddd xmm0,xmm0
 39:    66 0f 38 02 c0          phaddd xmm0,xmm0
 3e:    c3                      ret
```